# Combining multiple worksheets from multiple excel workbooks into a single workbook via. R

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx, xlconnect, r-xlsx

Lets say I have two excel workbooks (e.g. A.xlsx and B.xlsx) that each contain multiple worksheets (e.g. "a1" and "a2" in A.xlsx; "b1", "b2", and "b3" in B.xlsx). Note that these worksheets all have their own conditional formatting, filtering, zoom, and other viewing options.

Given this setup, is it possible to generate a combined workbook via. R (e.g. C.xlsx) featuring the 5 worksheets from A.xlsx and B.xlsx (e.g. "a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", and "b3" in C.xlsx) that furthermore retains all of the original conditional formatting, filtering, zoom, and other viewing options? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could read both the datasets together in `map2`.  Get the sheet names from 'A.xlsx' and 'B.xlsx' data. Create a named vector of filepath with sheet names, loop over the vector with `imap`, read the sheets with `read_excel`, bind those together after creating a column for identification of sheetname, and combine the `list` output from `imap` to a single `list` with `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)

# // replace the path/to/your - actual path
fileA <- 'path/to/your/A.xlsx'
fileB <- 'path/to/your/B.xlsx'
nmA <- excel_sheets(path = fileA)
nmB <- excel_sheets(path = fileB)
nm1A <- setNames(rep(fileA, length(nmA)), nmA)
nm1B <- setNames(rep(fileB, length(nmB)), nmB)
lstC <- imap(c(nm1A, nm1B), ~ 
              read_excel(.x, sheet = .y) %>%
                  mutate(sheetname = .y))
names(lstC) <- c(nmA, nmB)
write.xlsx(lstC, '/path/to/your/C.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. A couple of issues though, when I run the map2_dfr line of code, it results in the following error "Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:". I deleted one of the sheets in B.xlsx (b3 to be exact), but it then results in a different error (Error: Sheet 'b1' not found). Many thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output of `nmA` and `nmB`?  I assume that both have the same number of elements

Comment: @user3624032 sorry, i wa thinking that it is same length

Comment: nma results in: "a1" "a2"; while nmB  results in: "b1" "b2". When I had 3 sheets in B.xlsx, nmB results in "b1" "b2" "b3".

Comment: Thank you for helping - it shows the following error now: "Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232615/discussion-between-user3624032-and-akrun).

Comment: @user3624032 can you try now